# Attaching change listener to the jquery-chosen selects in a loop, not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am trying to init multiple chosen select in a loop:

```js
var arr = ["#key1", "#key2"];

for (var p in arr) {
    $(arr[p]).chosen().change(function () {
        console.log($(arr[p]).chosen().val());
    });
}
```

where the elements are:

```
<div>
    <select multiple="" id="key1">
        <option value="A1">A1</option>
        <option value="B1">B1</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <select multiple="" id="key2">
        <option value="A2">A2</option>
        <option value="B2">B2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The problem is, the **last** 'change' event handler is getting attached to all select elements. For example, selecting an item from "key1" prints `null` since the `.chosen().val()` is getting the values from "key2". Any suggestions?

Actually I wanted to store the selected values of each chosen into different fields, for instance, into of this object:

```
var selected_values = {
    selected_keys1 : {},
    selected_keys2 : {}
}
```

Comment: bindings in loop only affects last one, so this solutions are either use closure to solve it or just make a selector which should be comma separated based.

Comment: @Jai, I realized it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop to do this. You can retrieve both elements by separating the `id` selector with a comma. In the `change` handler you can then reference the element that raised the event using the `this` keyword. Try this:

```
$("#key1, #key2").chosen().change(function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L2h89tqe/)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Can you please see edit in the question. How can I store the selected values with comma separated lookup as you suggested in your answer?